# Single Linked List Reverse

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to learn linked lists. I am having a tiny bit of trouble. I've learnt some basic concepts. Such as reading in numbers in the list as shown here: My questions are:

1. Can anyone give me some hints on how to improve this code? I know it's quite messy.
2. If I were to reverse this linked list (keeping the addresses and content same) but manipulating the pointers.

How would I do so? I do NOT want the full solution, just some hints. If anyone can draw me any diagrams on how to reverse a linked list that would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

   struct node *pNew, *pHead, *pCurr;
   int i, dataEntered, numberOfNodes;
   printf("Please enter the amount of nodes: ");
   scanf("%d", &numberOfNodes);   

   for (i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++){
      printf("Enter data for node %d : ", numberOfNodes-i);
      scanf("%d", &dataEntered);     
      pNew = malloc (sizeof(struct node));
      pNew -> data = dataEntered;
      pNew -> next = pHead;
      pHead = pNew;   
   }

   pCurr = pHead;
   for (i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++){
      printf("Node %d has a data value of: %d\n", i, pCurr->data);
      pCurr = pCurr->next;

   }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are none of the existing questions about [reverse linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reverse+linked+list) helpful?

Comment: you need initialize pHead. `struct node *pNew, *pHead=NULL, *pCurr;`

Comment: The trick to learning this stuff is **break it down into the smallest possible steps.** Do you know how to (1) make an empty list, (2) test to see if a list is empty, (3) remove an element from the end of non-empty list, and (4) insert an element onto the beginning of a non-empty list?  If you can do those four things then you can reverse a linked list. Do you see how?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a bit code..

```
struct node *nex, *curr, *pre;
curr = phead;
pre = 0;
while(curr)
{
       nex = curr->next;
       curr->next = pre;
       pre = curr;
       curr = nex;
}
phead = pre;
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner coder Hitesh so I am not quite sure what `Node<T>` means

Answer (score 0):

For a linked-list reversal, it is pretty simple, just make a new linked list, where you put the new node to the end of the list (always traverse from the head of the second LList until the current node's next is null, then put the pNew to this current->next)